# Apache Camel test with mockEndpointsAndSkip() is not receiving messages, but weaveById().replace().to() is

Tags: java, apache-camel

I tried unit testing Apache Camel and I started out with a real basic case where my route looks like that:

```
public class TestRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("jpa:Data").to("jpa:Data").id("testId");
    }
}
```

Now the following approach didn't work. I tried mocking all endpoints, however I'm getting `mock://jpa:Data Received message count. Expected: <1> but was: <0>`

```
public class RouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    @Override
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new TestRoute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }

    @Test
    void testRoute() throws Exception {
        AdviceWith.adviceWith(context, null, false, a -> {
            a.replaceFromWith("direct:start");
            a.mockEndpointsAndSkip("*");
        });
        context.start();
        // The false here makes sure that I get an exception if I'm using a name 
        // of a nonexistent mocked endpoint, so that shouldn't be the problem here
        getMockEndpoint("mock:jpa:Data", false).expectedMessageCount(1);

        var data = getSomeTestData();
        template.sendBody("direct:start", data);
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

A workaround I found is replacing `a.mockEndpointsAndSkip("*");` with `a.weaveById("testId").replace().to("mock:jpa:Data");`. However I'm unsure what's the difference in this case, considering `mockEndpointsAndSkip` should also replace all endpoints with a mocked version. It would be a bit troublesome to replace ALL endpoints in a real scenario manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to the fact that by using `*` as pattern for the URI of endpoints to mock, you also include your *from* endpoint `direct:start` which implies that it is mocked too consequently the message is not transmitted to the rest of the route, therefore `mock:jpa:Data` doesn't receive any message.

Use a more specific pattern that matches only with your *to* endpoint like `jpa:Data`.

FYI, you can simplify your code by leveraging existing methods such as `replaceRouteFromWith` and `isMockEndpointsAndSkip` as next:

```
@Override
@BeforeEach
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // The new from endpoint for the route "testId"
    replaceRouteFromWith("testId", "direct:start");
    super.setUp();
}

@Override
protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new TestRoute();
}

@Override
public String isMockEndpointsAndSkip() {
    // The pattern of the URI of endpoints to mock 
    return "jpa:Data";
}

@Test
void testRoute() throws Exception {
    MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:jpa:Data")
    mockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);

    var data = getSomeTestData();
    template.sendBody("direct:start", data);
    mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```